# Application size increasing after running

Tags: windows, vb.net, executable, filesize, visual-studio-2010

I got a strange problem with my .NET application - I have included another .exe application using the resources in Visual Studio, after the compilation success the application weight is `9 621 504` bytes (been checking this with multiple ways and always showing the same value). "Magic" appears when I am checking the application weight with the following code:

`Dim mySize As New IO.FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath)`

The output of `mySize` is `11 575 296` bytes... (Windows is still showing that its `9 621 504` bytes) how is that possible?

Google has no results regarding this problem.

Packed resource application has only `2 252 800` bytes.

**EDIT :** I have noticed that it only happends on Windows 8, when I set compatibility mode to Windows 7 it works perfect.